# Layout of the buttons on the side menu

Tags: java, android, sidebar, navigationview

I'm in the process of moving buttons from the main activity on the navigation view / side bar.

I wonder if there is any way that moved the LinearLayout with two buttons from the main activity to the side menu.

Is it any way? 
I ask, because I do not see the option to add buttons, I can only add Items. ( in navigation view)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a custom layout for your navigation like this http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/